# Flutter listview.builder doesn't show more than 10 products but I have 100 products

Tags: android, ios, json, flutter, flutter-getx

```
class IlacProductRepo extends GetxService {
  final ApiClient apiClient;

  IlacProductRepo({required this.apiClient});

  Future<Response> getIlacProductList() async {
    return await apiClient.getData(AppConstans.ALL_PRODUCT_ILAC);
  }
}
```

---

```
class IlacProductController extends GetxController {
  final IlacProductRepo ilacProductRepo;
  IlacProductController({required this.ilacProductRepo});
  List<dynamic> _ilacproductList = [];
  List<dynamic> get ilacproductList => _ilacproductList;

  bool _isLoaded = false;
  bool get isLoaded => _isLoaded ;

  Future<void> getIlacProductList() async {
    Response response = await ilacProductRepo.getIlacProductList();
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print("got ilaç");
      _ilacproductList = [];
      _ilacproductList.addAll(Product.fromJson(response.body).products);
      _isLoaded=true;
      update();
    } else {return print("something wrong");}
  }
}
```

//another page

```
case Page.ilac:
        return GetBuilder<IlacProductController>(builder: (ilacProduct) {
          return ilacProduct.isLoaded
              ? ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  itemCount: ilacProduct.ilacproductList.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Get.toNamed(RouteHelper.getIlacProduct(index));
                      },
                      child: Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                              left: Dimensions.width20,
                              right: Dimensions.width10,
                              bottom: Dimensions.height15),
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              //image section
                              Container(
                                width: Dimensions.listViewImgSize,
                                height: Dimensions.listViewImgSize,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                        Dimensions.radius20),
                                    color: Colors.white38,
                                    image: DecorationImage(
                                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                        image: NetworkImage(
                                            AppConstans.BASE_URL +
                                                AppConstans.UPLOAD_URL +
                                                ilacProduct
                                                    .ilacproductList[index]
                                                    .img!))),
                              ),
                              //text section
                              Expanded(
                                child: Container(
                                  height: Dimensions.listViewTextContSize,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                          topRight: Radius.circular(
                                              Dimensions.radius20),
                                          bottomRight: Radius.circular(
                                              Dimensions.radius20)),
                                      color: Colors.white),
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                        left: Dimensions.width10,
                                        right: Dimensions.width10),
                                    child: Column(
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                      children: [
                                        BigText(
                                          text: ilacProduct
                                              .ilacproductList[index].name!,
                                        ),
                                        SizedBox(
                                          height: Dimensions.height10,
                                        ),
                                        ExpandableProductText(text: ilacProduct
                                            .ilacproductList[index].description!),
                                        SizedBox(
                                          height: Dimensions.height10,
                                        ),

                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          )),
                    );
                  })
              : const CircularProgressIndicator(
                  color: AppColor.mainColor,
                );
        });
        break;
```

As I mentioned in the title, I will have close to 1000 products, but at the moment, there are no more than 10 in the application.

I don't know what the problem is, I think it can't be item count, I wonder if I made a logic error in the controller part?

As I mentioned in the title, I will have close to 1000 products, but at the moment, there are no more than 10 in the application.

I don't know what the problem is, I think it can't be item count, I wonder if I made a logic error in the controller part?

Comment: What does it mean that 'no more than 10 in the application'? `ListView.builder` will only build visible items in the list. To build all items use `ListView` constructor.

Comment: @PeterKoltai but that is counter-intuitive. If there are 1000 items then its best to use ListView.builder.

Comment: Try to print the decoded response.body and print ilacProduct.ilacproductList.length to get more clue on where your issue might be. If you can't print response.body then perhaps try testing your response in Postman? Print statements are very helpful in figuring out where your issue might be.

Comment: 10 products appear in postman, but there are 195 products in MySQL

Comment: List view builder only creates items items when they are scrolled onto the screen. Not sure if that is the issue you are referring to. https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/lists/long-lists